# MS Access 2013: Change label caption in report based on checkbox in form

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I've `checkbox (Name:chkHead; Caption:Out of Office)` in form and `label(Name:lblHead; Caption: Name of office head)` in report.

Detailed image:

[image: Detailed image]

When I click in Report button in form it generates report based on a specific query.
If the checkbox in form is checked then the label caption needs to be "Head in Charge" otherwise it will the name of the office head.

I'm using MS Access 2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create two labels ---> 1. Name of office head 2. Head in charge
2. Click the check box in design view of the form and choose 'property sheet' under Design tab
3. In the 'property sheet' on the right side select the 'On Click' under 'Event' and choose 'Code Builder' in it.

   4. Write the code similar to the below inside sub()

      If Me!**MyCheckBox** = True Then

      Me.**Label2**.Visible = True

      Me.**Label2**.Visible = False

      Else if Me!**MyCheckBox** = False Then

      Me.**Label2**.Visible = False

      Me.**Label2**.Visible = True

Comment: Thanks for your response. Both controls are not in the form. Checkbox is in the form and label is in the report. I've uploaded an image with my problems. Hope you will be able to manage some time to help me.

Comment: just use Report![your_report_name]![label_name].visible=True or Report![your_report_name]![label_name].visible=False accordingly...

Comment: Your suggestion has helped me to find a way out. I've used these code and have got expected result.
Private Sub Report_Load()
    lblMayor.Visible = True
End Sub


Private Sub cmdReport_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenReport "Nationality", acViewPreview
    If chkMayor.Value = True Then
        Report_Nationality.lblMayor.Visible = False
    Else
        Report_Nationality.lblMayor.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub